# How to prevent Alerts conditionally based on the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have the following scenario where I need to prevent alert box from appearing when the message is "hi". For all other cases, the alert box should appear.

```
window.alert = function(text) {
  if(text=='hi') {
    console.log('Prevented alert Box');
  } else {
    // Continue displaying Alert. 
  }
};
```

I'm not sure of the right approach here. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're overriding the default window.alert huh, well logically that code should do well. What's the problem except for the approach?

Comment: try saving  a reference to old alert and then boom :)   https://jsfiddle.net/1w7hk82n/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the original version of `alert` by doing something like this:

```
window.originalAlert = window.alert;
```

Then redefine alert as you've done above like this:

```
window.alert = function(text) {
  if(text=='hi') {
    console.log('Prevented alert Box');
  } else {
    window.originalAlert(text); 
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep a reference to the old alert..

eg.

```js
var old_alert = window.alert;

window.alert = function(text) {
  if(text=='hi') {
    console.log('Prevented alert Box');
  } else {
    old_alert(text);
  }
};

alert("hi");
alert("there");
```

Comment: Awesome... Thanks (y)